# How to solve these errors in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, nullreferenceexception, unityscript

I am newbie in unity. And I am creating 2-d game by taking help from some links. My game working fine. But when character destroyed game start from start point as usual but its pause there. And show some errors I dont know how to solve these errors.

PlayerRespawn.js-

```
var Player : GameObject;
var SpawnPoint: Transform;

function OnTriggerEnter(other: Collider) {
Destroy(other.gameObject);
var P: GameObject= Instantiate(Player,SpawnPoint.position,Quaternion.identity);

var sf = Camera.main.GetComponent(SmoothFollow2);
sf.target=P.transform;
}
```

SmoothFollow2.js-

```
var target : Transform;
var distance = 3.0;
var height = 3.0;
var damping = 5.0;
var smoothRotation = true;
var rotationDamping = 10.0;
var lockRotation : boolean;

function Update () {
    var wantedPosition = target.TransformPoint(0, height, -distance);
    transform.position = Vector3.Lerp (transform.position, wantedPosition, Time.deltaTime * damping);

    if (smoothRotation) {
        var wantedRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(target.position - transform.position, target.up);
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp (transform.rotation, wantedRotation, Time.deltaTime * rotationDamping);
    }


    else transform.LookAt (target, target.up);

    if (lockRotation){
    transform.localRotation=Quaternion.EulerAngles(0,0,0);
    }
}
```

And the errors I am getting are-

```
NullReferenceException
PlayerRespawn.OnTriggerEnter (UnityEngine.Collider other) (at Assets/MyScripts/PlayerRespawn.js:8)
MissingReferenceException: The object of type 'Transform' has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it.
```

Comment: which is line 8 in your code? (the line that's throwing the error).

Comment: var sf = Camera.main.GetComponent(SmoothFollow2); this is line 8.

Comment: But I dont know how to solve this.

Comment: How many cameras are in the scene? If > 1, which is considered as main camera (tag = MainCamera)? Is `SmoothFollow2` active at all during the first run before game over (some Debug.Log for testing)? Is it just one scene or are other scenes loaded? If so, additionally?

Comment: @Kay Only one main camera. **SmoothFollow2** active all the time during first run before game over. Only one scene.

Comment: It appears to me like Steven said: The camera is attached to `other` and thus destroyed. Does the error still occur if you comment out the line `Destroy(other.gameObject);`?

Answer (score 3):

Considering the line that throws the error is:

```
var sf = Camera.main.GetComponent(SmoothFollow2);
```

It sounds like perhaps your camera has been destroyed. One way to check for this is to stick a Debug message in your trigger, to see what exactly is being destroyed. Try putting `Debug.LogWarning(other.gameObject.name);` at the beginning of your `OnTriggerEnter(other: Collider)` function. If you see the camera name show up as a warning, then you know this is the case.

You can prevent this by doing:

```
if(other.gameObject.name == Camera.main.gameObject.name)
    return;
```

A better solution, if there's only a limited range of items that need to be destroyed, is to allow only those to continue through the `OnTriggerEnter`.

Answer (score 0):

I would not destroy the player. I would just disable and then enable it again in another defined position, or the initial position.

By doing this your camera, which is following your player by the var "target" will always have the referenced object and will stop throwing the error for you.

to disable a game object:

```
gameObject.SetActive = false;
```

To enable it again:

```
gameObject.SetActive = true;
```

I hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

i solved the issue  by making sure that the main camera was attached to the player as a child before  creating the Player Prefab so that when it re spawns it has the main camera

hope this helps you solve your issue

"OK for added value i know the tutorial your working with and to help in understanding my post above what you need to do is, before making your prefab of the player(first person controller) in your hierarchy in the unity editor drag and drop the main camera onto the (first person controller) then make that your prefab of Player. – "

Comment: To add value to your answer and help a user who mentioned as a newbie in Unity, you could add some code sample to the answer. For example, how do you attached SmoothFollow2 (the camera obj. in this question) to the player as a child?